# Upgrading to El Capitan GM Candidate loses all Exchange folders in Mail

Tags: mail.app, exchange-activesync, macos

I upgraded from current Yosemite to the El Capitan GM Candidate this morning. For work, I have an Exchange account with a bunch of folders in Apple Mail. Upon starting Mail after the upgrade, my folders were no longer present; Mail synced a few thousand messages, but it does not show the folders that are on the server.

I dug through the Exchange account preferences and the Mail preferences, but I haven't been able to find anything. Does anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: As I found on http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/70174/os-x-mail-app-old-mail-not-downloading-showing-after-reconfiguring-exchange-acc - I expect that using Mailbox > Rebuild might be able to help.

Comment: Ah, looks like that may have helped. Or at least, after Mailbox > Rebuild, I still had to restart Mail to actually see my folders (and it's possible that a Mail restart without Rebuild would have fixed it, I guess?).

Comment: Please [report this experience to Apple](https://www.apple.com/feedback) using the Feedback Assistant – assuming it is in the *GM Candidate*; every report helps!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by entering the passwords into Mail > Preferences > Accounts instead of Mail > Accounts (Internet Accounts in System Preferences) and it saved the passwords without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Have deleted my full account in mail, then added again the same account (after checking on webmail that all folders are still there) and it took a while to get all emails back but it seemed to work. Everything is back again, including the original folder structure. Does anyone know how I can trace these emails in Finder? Can't find them and would like to back-up these